# numpy reshaping error - CNN's

Tags: arrays, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm using Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda on Mac. Along with Keras and Tensorflow for neural network building.

I've resized images, and moved them into a directory. They're RGB images (3 color channels). After flattening images, and splitting into training/testing for my CNN and it is not letting me reshape my images. The training set that i'm attempting to reshape has 7151 images in with size 256 by 256. Here is the code:

```
img_rows, img_cols = 256, 256

# number of channels
img_channels = 3

#%%
#  data

path1 = 'C:\\Users\\PALASH\\Desktop\\safeunsafe\\inputdata'#path of folder of images    
path2 = 'C:\\Users\\PALASH\\Desktop\\safeunsafe\\resizeddata'   #path of folder to save images 

listing = os.listdir(path1) 
num_samples=size(listing)

#for file in listing:
#    im = Image.open(path1 + '\\' + file)   
#    img = im.resize((img_rows,img_cols))
#    gray = img.convert('L')
                #need to do some more processing here           
#    gray.save(path2 +'\\' +  file, "JPEG")

imlist = os.listdir(path2)

im1 = array(Image.open('C:\\Users\\NAME\\Desktop\\safeunsafe\\resizeddata' + '\\'+ imlist[0])) # open one image to get size
m,n = im1.shape[0:2] # get the size of the images
imnbr = len(imlist) # get the number of images

# create matrix to store all flattened images
immatrix = array([array(Image.open('C:\\Users\\NAME\\Desktop\\safeunsafe\\resizeddata'+ '\\' + im2))#.flatten()
              for im2 in imlist],'f')

label=np.ones((num_samples,),dtype = int)
label[0:5723]=0
label[5723:]=1

data,Label = shuffle(immatrix,label, random_state=2)
train_data = [data,Label]


(X, y) = (train_data[0],train_data[1])


# STEP 1: split X and y into training and testing sets

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=4)


**X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],3,img_rows,img_cols)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 3, img_rows, img_cols)**
```

code right above is what returns this error:

`**cannot reshape array of size 468647936 into shape (7151,3,256,256)**`

How do I fix this problem? I'm trying to train a CNN with RGB images, and i've realized that it does not reshape properly as 7151 * 3 * 256 * 256 does not equal the original shape. What should I change to properly reshape the image?

Here is my current model:

```
`model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(26,26), input_shape=(256,256,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(14,14))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(9,9))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(3,3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dense(2))
```

Here is the summary of my model:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 231, 231, 32)      64928     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 231, 231, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 218, 218, 14)      87822     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 218, 218, 14)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 210, 210, 9)       10215     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 105, 105, 9)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 103, 103, 3)       246       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 103, 103, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 51, 51, 3)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 7803)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               998912    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 130       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 2)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 1,170,509
Trainable params: 1,170,509
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

Comment: `7151*3*256*256` is 1405943808.  That's 3*468647936.  `reshape` cannot change the number of elements in an array.

Comment: @hpaulj i've updated my question.

Comment: What is the number of features that you used in the last layer? Downsampling happens in CNN because of the max-pooling. verified with:
 (`In [8]: 7151 * 256 * 256 * 3 > 468647936
Out[8]: True`). If you can give the feature size and dimensions of last layer then reshape is trivial.